# Convert Button onClick function to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently have code in HTML, but would like to convert it to JavaScript. You can see the codes below:

I'd like to convert the following to JQuery (instead of in HTML):

```
<button id="1" onclick="swapStyleSheet('style1.css')">Button1</button>
<button id="2" onclick="swapStyleSheet('style2.css')">Button2</button>
<button id="3" onclick="swapStyleSheet('style3.css')">Button3</button>
```

The above code triggers this:

```
var swapStyleSheet = function (sheet) {
  document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
  storebackground(sheet);
}

var storebackground = function (swapstylesheet) {
  localStorage.setItem("sheetKey", swapstylesheet); //you need to give a key and value
}

var loadbackground = function () {
  document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', localStorage.getItem('sheetKey'));
}

window.onload = loadbackground();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Check `jquery's` `on` and data attributes.

Comment: i dont see jquery related codes.. OP please clarify

Comment: If you want to assign the handler to the button in JS, you may check `addEventListener("eventName", functionRef)`

Comment: @web-nomad Sorry, was that jquery? I'm a designer by trade and kinda Frankenstein these codes together that I found and I don't know the difference. If it's jquery, how do I convert the html portion to jquery?

Comment: @guradio Sorry, was that jquery? I'm a designer by trade and kinda Frankenstein these codes together that I found and I don't know the difference. If it's jquery, how do I convert the html portion to jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this..

```js
// Here we get all the buttons
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

// We loop the buttons
for (var i=0; i<button.length; i++){

  // Here we add a click event for each buttons
  button[i].onclick = function() {
    alert("style"+this.id+".css");
    //swapStyleSheet("style"+this.id+".css"); you can do it something like that;
  }
}
var swapStyleSheet = function (sheet) {
        //document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
        //storebackground(sheet);
    }

var storebackground = function (swapstylesheet) {
       // localStorage.setItem("sheetKey", swapstylesheet); //you need to give a key and value
    }

var loadbackground = function () {
        //document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', localStorage.getItem('sheetKey'));
    }

//window.onload = loadbackground();
```

```html
<button id="1">Button1</button>
<button id="2" >Button2</button>
<button id="3" >Button3</button>
```

No need for **JQuery**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are just looking for click event handlers. Here's a version using jQuery. I commented out the code dealing with the missing 'pagestyle' element and localstorage to prevent js errors in the StackOverflow snippet.

```js
var swapStyleSheet = function (sheet) {
        console.log( 'sheet: ' + sheet ); // look at the console when you press a button
        //document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
        //storebackground(sheet);
    }

var storebackground = function (swapstylesheet) {
        //localStorage.setItem("sheetKey", swapstylesheet); //you need to give a key and value
    }

var loadbackground = function () {
        //document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', localStorage.getItem('sheetKey'));
    }

window.onload = loadbackground();

$( '#1' ).on( 'click', function() {
    swapStyleSheet('style1.css');
});
$( '#2' ).on( 'click', function() {
    swapStyleSheet('style2.css');
});
$( '#3' ).on( 'click', function() {
    swapStyleSheet('style3.css');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="1">Button1</button>
<button id="2">Button2</button>
<button id="3">Button3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="1" class='changestyle' data-stylesheet = "style1.css">Button1</button>
<button id="2" class='changestyle' data-stylesheet = "style2.css">Button2</button>
<button id="3" class='changestyle' data-stylesheet = "style3.css">Button3</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $(".changestyle").on("click", function(){
        $("#pagestyle").attr("href", $(this).data('stylesheet'));
    })
})
```